# Redirect to Requested URL after GMAIL authentication in JAVA

Tags: java, authentication, gmail, google-oauth, redirect

The use-case of what I'm trying to achieve is as follows:

When some user is added to an Account and I provide a URL to the associated account users in mail, now when the account user clicks on the user's profile URL provided in mail and the account user isn't already logged in.

So now after the account user authenticates himself using the Gmail authentication, he should get redirected to the link which he clicked in the email.

Current Scenario: after clicked on link from email user is redirecting to login page if it's not logged in in system but if user choose the option of "Login With Gmail", then user get logged in with gmail successfully but is redirecting to the home page of system instead of some requested URL.

I'm using Spring and I'm able to achieve this functionality in case if user has application login credentials, however I'm unable to do so using Gmail.

I've found a few plugins however I can't use them. Any help would be appreciated, Thanks !